# Gems missing after deployment (Ruby, Ruby on Rails, Capistrano)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, capistrano

I'm creating a Rails app. I deployed to a vps server by Capistrano, running the following deploy command:

```
$ bundle exec cap development deploy
```

And the deploying looked like success, but some gems were missing.

```
The following gems are missing
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * debug_inspector (0.0.3)
 * web-console (3.1.1)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * spring (1.7.2)
 * spring-watcher-listen (2.0.0)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * rails-controller-testing (0.1.1)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * ansi (1.5.0)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
 * minitest-reporters (1.1.9)
 * formatador (0.2.5)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * lumberjack (1.0.12)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * nenv (0.3.0)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * shellany (0.0.1)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * notiffany (0.1.1)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * coderay (1.1.1)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * slop (3.6.0)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * pry (0.10.4)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * guard (2.13.0)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * guard-compat (1.2.1)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]        * guard-minitest (2.4.4)
 DEBUG [16b13d82]       Install missing gems with `bundle install`
```

I want to installing the missing gems.

**The specs are:**

- ubuntu 16.04
- Bundler 1.14.6
- ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
- Rails 5.1.2
- capistrano 3
- cloud9 (local environment)

**My Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',  '5.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6' 
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'toastr-rails'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.5'
gem 'private_pub'
gem 'thin'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'payjp'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.6'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.3'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-passenger'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
gem 'capistrano-safe-deploy-to'
gem 'listen', '~> 3.1.5'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

**My Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.3)
      nio4r (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.3)
      actionview (= 5.0.3)
      activejob (= 5.0.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.0.3)
      actionview (= 5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
    activerecord (5.0.3)
      activemodel (= 5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.1)
      public_suffix (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.2)
    airbrussh (1.3.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)
    ansi (1.5.0)
    arel (7.1.4)
    autoprefixer-rails (7.1.2.2)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.10)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.2.3)
    capistrano (3.8.2)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (1.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-passenger (0.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
    capistrano-rails (1.3.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rbenv (2.1.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-safe-deploy-to (1.1.1)
      capistrano (>= 3.0)
    capistrano3-unicorn (0.2.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1, >= 3.1.0)
    carrierwave (1.1.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    climate_control (0.2.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.1)
    coffee-rails (4.2.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.2.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    cookiejar (0.3.3)
    daemons (1.2.4)
    debug_inspector (0.0.3)
    devise (4.3.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.2)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    domain_name (0.5.20170404)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    em-http-request (1.1.5)
      addressable (>= 2.3.4)
      cookiejar (!= 0.3.1)
      em-socksify (>= 0.3)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.3)
      http_parser.rb (>= 0.6.0)
    em-socksify (0.3.1)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.3)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faraday (0.12.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    faye (1.2.4)
      cookiejar (>= 0.3.0)
      em-http-request (>= 0.3.0)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
      faye-websocket (>= 0.9.1)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.5.1)
    faye-websocket (0.10.7)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.5.1)
    ffi (1.9.18)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.2)
    font-awesome-sass (4.7.0)
      sass (>= 3.2)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    geocoder (1.4.4)
    globalid (0.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    guard (2.13.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, <= 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-minitest (2.4.4)
      guard-compat (~> 1.2)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    hashie (3.5.6)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (0.8.6)
    jbuilder (2.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.1.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    jwt (1.5.6)
    kgio (2.11.0)
    libv8 (3.16.14.19)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.12)
    mail (2.6.6)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.2.0)
    minitest (5.10.2)
    minitest-reporters (1.1.9)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (4.1.0)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nio4r (2.1.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.0)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.2.0)
    notiffany (0.1.1)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    oauth (0.5.3)
    oauth2 (1.4.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.13)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
    omniauth (1.6.1)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6, < 3.6.0)
      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)
    omniauth-facebook (4.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.5.0)
      jwt (~> 1.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth (>= 1.1.1)
      omniauth-oauth2 (>= 1.3.1)
    omniauth-oauth (1.1.0)
      oauth
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-twitter (1.4.0)
      omniauth-oauth (~> 1.1)
      rack
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (5.1.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.0)
    payjp (0.0.5)
      rest-client (~> 2.0)
    pg (0.18.4)
    polyamorous (1.3.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    private_pub (1.0.3)
      faye
    pry (0.10.4)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    public_suffix (2.0.5)
    puma (3.4.0)
    rack (2.0.3)
    rack-mini-profiler (0.10.5)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (5.0.3)
      actioncable (= 5.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.3)
      actionview (= 5.0.3)
      activejob (= 5.0.3)
      activemodel (= 5.0.3)
      activerecord (= 5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 5.0.3)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-controller-testing (0.1.1)
      actionpack (~> 5.x)
      actionview (~> 5.x)
      activesupport (~> 5.x)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails-i18n (5.0.4)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      railties (~> 5.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (5.0.3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.18.0)
    rake (12.0.0)
    ransack (1.8.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    rb-readline (0.5.4)
    ref (2.0.0)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    rest-client (2.0.2)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    rmagick (2.16.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    sass (3.5.1)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.7.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.0)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (~> 1.2)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.13)
    sshkit (1.14.0)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    therubyracer (0.12.3)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.15)
      ref
    thin (1.7.2)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (>= 1, < 3)
    thor (0.19.4)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.7)
    toastr-rails (1.0.3)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
    tzinfo (1.2.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.4)
    unicorn (5.3.0)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    warden (1.2.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (3.1.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.2)
      debug_inspector
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.6.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
    will_paginate (3.1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.6)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 0.0.10)
  capistrano (~> 3.6)
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-passenger
  capistrano-rails (~> 1.3)
  capistrano-rbenv
  capistrano-safe-deploy-to
  capistrano3-unicorn
  carrierwave
  coffee-rails (= 4.2.1)
  devise
  font-awesome-rails
  font-awesome-sass
  geocoder
  guard (= 2.13.0)
  guard-minitest (= 2.4.4)
  jbuilder (= 2.4.1)
  jquery-rails (= 4.1.1)
  jquery-ui-rails (= 5.0.5)
  listen (~> 3.1.5)
  minitest-reporters (= 1.1.9)
  omniauth
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-google-oauth2
  omniauth-twitter
  paperclip
  payjp
  pg (= 0.18.4)
  private_pub
  puma (= 3.4.0)
  rack-mini-profiler
  rails (= 5.0.3)
  rails-controller-testing (= 0.1.1)
  rails-i18n
  rails_12factor
  ransack
  rb-readline
  rmagick
  sass-rails (>= 3.2)
  spring (= 1.7.2)
  spring-watcher-listen (= 2.0.0)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.13)
  therubyracer
  thin
  toastr-rails
  turbolinks (= 5.0.1)
  uglifier (= 3.0.0)
  unicorn
  web-console (= 3.1.1)
  will_paginate (= 3.1.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.15.1
```

**My Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.4.1'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano3/unicorn'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/safe_deploy_to'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gems that are reported as missing are all gems from the development and test groups. All other gems are there.

Answer (score 0):

you may check [capistrano bundler](https://github.com/capistrano/bundler#usage), as this in your production server not the Gem files in your development, you should also install the gemfiles in you production, since you deploy with capistrano then you must include in your **Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/bundler'
```

with this command Capistrano will run the bundle install in your production server during the deploy.

Comment: i added my capfile to my question.

Comment: have you run cap production bundler:install ?

Comment: no. cap "production" bundler:install? though i want to deploy on development

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything left to install.

capistrano-bundler first checks if any gems are missing. That is why you see the "the following gems are missing" message. Then it automatically proceeds to install those missing gems.

If you deploy a second time, you shouldn't see the "missing" message, because now all the gems are installed.

Comment: thanks for advice, Matt. but when I deployed again,  I saw the "the following gems are missing" message...why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I suppose that could happen if you aren't using a shared location for the `:bundle_path`. But if you are using the default settings that should never be a problem.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I'm terribly sorry but, would you tell me how to check using the default setting? I may have changed that, but I don't know.

Comment: `:/var/www/myapp/development/shared/bundle/ruby$ ls`
`2.3.0  2.4.0`

This is my pass.

Comment: `bundle exec cap development doctor` will show all settings. It looks like you are using the default, so that is not the problem. Sorry I can't be of any more help!